# Jquery ui $([])

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

This is just a quick one (I hope).

I've recently been on to the jquery ui dialog pages to look at using form inside a dialog http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form and I noticed some code that I hadn't seen before:

```
var allFields = $([]).add(#input1).add(input2).add(input3)....
```

I was just wondering what $([]) meant?

At first I thought it was a way to create an array in jquery but when I try:

```
allFields.add(input4)
```

after the variable is declared nothing else is being added?!?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)
I've tried googling this, however, I'm not having much luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) function accepts a number of different arguments, one of which is an array of DOM elements. Passing such an array will result in a new jQuery object, containing those elements, being returned. In this case they're passing an empty array, so it returns a jQuery object containing zero elements.

The [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) function will add more elements to an existing set.

So `$([])` creates a jQuery object containing no elements, `.add('#input1')` would add the element with an `id` of `input1` to that set. Calling `.add('#input1')` again would add nothing because the element is already present.

Comment: Thanks, Anthony. I originally posted to a php script and it returned all the values that were initially added. When I tried adding a further element e.g. var allFields = $([]).add(input1).add(input2);allfields.add(input3) in only returned the 2 original values rather than all 3?

Comment: @RossWilson What are `input1`, `input2` and `input3`?

Comment: @RossWilson: The `add` method creates a new set and returns it. You'd need to reassign `allFields`: `allFields = allFields.add(input3)`

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - input1, input2, input3 were just variable names that i was using for the example. Sorry, I realise that it was quite vague.

Answer (score 0):

```
var allFields = $([]);
allFields.add()
```

in your question you're equaling the variable to the  return value of the .add() method